# Iterate through a dictionary of Subs/Functions and call them

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get the pointer to a function (like in C++) in VB.net and add it to a dictionary to be called later. I have no idea how to do this in VB but I know it's easily done in C++ using void*. I really want to avoid having 8000 global variables such as nextTime_RunSub1, nextTime_RunSub2, etc with a very big `Select Case` or `If` statement.

For example:

```
Public dictOfNewThinkFuncsToAdd As New Dictionary (Of ?, Single) 'Function/Sub, Time To Call

Private Sub Main()
    Dim dictOfThinkFuncs As New Dictionary (Of ?, Single) 'Function/Sub, Time To Call
    dictOfThinkFuncs.Add(AddressOf(Sub1), GetCurrentTime() + 5)
    dictOfThinkFuncs.Add(AddressOf(Sub2), GetCurrentTime() + 6)
    Dim removalQueue As New List(Of ?)

    Do
        Dim bRemoveFunc As Boolean = False
        Dim bAddFunc As Boolean = False
        For iter As Integer = 0 To dictOfThinkFuncs.Count - 1
            If GetCurrentTime() >= dictOfThinkFuncs(iter).Value Then
                CallFunction(dictOfThinkFuncs(iter).Key)
                removalQueue.Add(dictOfThinkFuncs(iter).Key)
                bRemoveFunc = True
            End If
        Next

        If bRemoveFunc Then
            For Each func In removalQueue
                dictOfThinkFuncs.Remove(func)
            Next
            removalQueue.Clear()
        End If

        For Each func In dictOfNewThinkFuncsToAdd
            dictOfThinkFuncs.Add(func.Key, func.Value)
            bAddFunc = True
        Next

        If bAddFunc Then
            dictOfNewThinkFuncsToAdd.Clear()
        End If

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Sub1()
    DoStuff()
    dictOfNewThinkFuncsToAdd.Add(AddressOf(Sub3), GetCurrentTime() + 15)
End Sub

Private Sub Sub2()
    DoStuff()
    dictOfNewThinkFuncsToAdd.Add(AddressOf(Sub2), GetCurrentTime() + 15)
End Sub

Private Sub Sub3()
    DoStuff()
End Sub
```

Comment: So "which part" is the problem? And how does such problem manifest itself?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to add the name of or a function/sub  pointer to a dictionary and call it from there

Comment: I see some code that appears to be attempting to do such - so what part "doesn't work"? Explain the actual observed behavior and/or error messages.

Comment: Your "functions" are all void methods or `Subs` in VB-speak.  This seems like an XY question: you could add Action delegates to the dictionary but it seems like well designed classes could eliminate the need for that (and "8000 global vars")

Comment: The very first line. The '?' is what I don't know. Also, CallFunction is just something I made up to give an example as to how it should work

Comment: [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx) are what you are looking for. If you described the larger problem you are trying to solve, there may be a better way to approach what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This work (both formats).  So you can either wrap your calls inside a uniform return or just do addressOf if they are all same type of function with no params.

It's not exactly your code (I know... I know).  But gives you a quick example of a dictionary of Lambda functions.  And it's vb.net.

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim getters As New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Boolean))
        getters.Add("First", New Func(Of Boolean)(Function() 
            Console.WriteLine("Test Run")
            Return true
        End Function))
        getters.Add("Second", AddressOf TestMe)

        For each el In getters.Values
            el()
        Next

    End Sub

    Public function TestMe() As boolean
        Console.WriteLine("Test Run")
        Return true
    End function

End Module
```

**Dictionary(of Action, Single) works too...**

I guess you can do that without the return parameter, too (the vb.net equivalent of `void function()` is `Sub()` which is an object of type Action as seen below).

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim getters As New Dictionary(Of String, Action)
        getters.Add("First", New Action(sub() 
            TestMe()
        End sub))
        getters.Add("Second", AddressOf TestMe2)
        For each el In getters.Values
            el()
        Next

    End Sub

    Public Sub TestMe2() 
        Console.WriteLine("Test Run")
    End Sub

    Public function TestMe() As boolean
        Console.WriteLine("Test Run")
        Return true
    End function

End Module
```